# Как Symfony определяет, что бандлы лежат в папке [src]

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Если мы сгенерировали бандл, то он будет находиться в папке [src].

Как Symfony загружает что-либо из этой папки?

Посмотрел автозагрузчики, но что-то не нашёл нигде упоминания об этой папке ('src').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сам `Symfony3` не загружает классы, этим занимается сгенерированный автолоадер `composer'а`, вы можете найти упоминание о папке `src` в директиве `autoload` в файле `composer.json`

Например, для стандартной установки, там указано `"psr-4": { "": "src/" },`, следовательно ваш типичный бандл будет находиться по пути `src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php`, и полное название класса будет `AppBundle\AppBundle`.